# How to scale text shadow offset when importing a canvas image in FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, todataurl

I am use FabricJS and Text Shadow offset not apply as it is when rendering image as display on canvas.

The text display on canvas as follows

[image]

But after saving the canvas image it display as follows.

[image]

The shadow offset got reduced.

My shadow offset function as follows

```
function textShadowOffsetChange() {
    var val = $('#text-shadow-offset-slider').slider('option','value');
    if(document.getElementById("text-shadow-set").checked && isText()) {
        currentElement.setShadow({
            color: '#000',
            blur: 5,
            offsetX: val,
            offsetY: val
        });
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
```

I thin this happens with saving function. Because I have use multiplier and scale the image when it saving. My save function as follows?

```
var MaskImg = canvas.toDataURL({
       format: 'png',
       multiplier: multi,
       left: (canvas.width - maskWidth)/2,
       height: maskOriHeight/multi,
       width: maskOriWidth/multi
});
```

I think the multiplier not affected to shadow offset. How I solve this?

[Sample Fiddle](http://codepen.io/isurufit/pen/woKWzw)

Comment: Can you please make a plunker or jsfiddle to see it in action?

Comment: @janusz http://codepen.io/isurufit/pen/woKWzw

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in Fabric.JS which has already been fixed in version 1.6.6. Just update to v1.6.6 and it will work fine, see here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBvpaK

They seem to have changed the Canvas constructor in v1.6.6 so that now it gets a reference to the DOM element like this:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById('c'));
```